# In android 5.0 and 6.0 don't work javascript in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

In my app, I have an activity with webView. On the version of android 5.0 and 6.0 webView don't display icons or some button or navigations menu(slider and search bar too).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y889w.png)

But in android above 6.0, all is ok.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D69zx.png)

It is my webView code:
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
        if (newProgress == 100) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
        if (super.getDefaultVideoPoster() == null) {  // fix for android 6.0
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 50, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } else {
            return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();
        }
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(infoModel.getUrl());
```

I tried it:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

but it did not work

Comment: Have you updated [System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en_GB) from the google play store? I had a similar issue with Android 5 - and updating system webview solved it.

Comment: Yes, I have the last version